# Window 7 time limit for Kids but allow installation

Tags: windows-7, uac

Hi I'm trying to set up Window 7 so that it will block access after 9pm for a teenager . However, he can perform installation of anything he wants. I can't manage to do both because to set up parental control a user account have to be standard user. A standard user cannot install anything without UAC prompt. If I turn off UAC, he can just turn off the time limit himself in his own account ( I tried ). I disabled Local group policy for UAC : Detect application installations and prompt for elevation. but it seems only works on Administrator. Standard user still need admin password to install anything.

I need a way to block access to computer after 9pm but allow everything else (except changing time limit setting).

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but as you suggested, these two things are mutually exclusive.  In order to install software on Windows 7, the user needs to be an Administrator.  If the user is an Administrator, they can basically override anything you do to set a power off time, assuming they can figure out how.